# Searx (based on Nginx) "Let's Encrypt" SSL certificate is not valid for Safari (iPhone and MacOS), it is valid for the rest of the world

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a customized installation of Searx (https://searx.me/) at:
https://ricercaalternativa.mydissent.net/

It has been working properly with Letsencrypt for years now. As of a few days ago, however, the certificate provided by Letsencrypt is compatible with everything except Apple (Safari on iPhone and on macOS).

This test shows a "chain issue":
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ricercaalternativa.mydissent.net

I don't know how to solve the problem (and actually what is the meaning of this issue), also because the SSL certificate installation has always been fully automated with the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
YOUR_DOMAIN="ricercaalternativa.mydissent.net"
certbot certonly -d ${YOUR_DOMAIN} --manual --preferred-challenges dns
service uwsgi restart
service nginx restart
```

Anyway, `--preferred-challenges dns` seems ignored: it doesn't ask me to deploy a DNS record. This is the output:

```
# ./updateSSL.sh 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator manual, Installer None
Cert not yet due for renewal

You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry.
(ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/ricercaalternativa.mydissent.net.conf)

What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Keep the existing certificate for now
2: Renew & replace the cert (limit ~5 per 7 days)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 2
Renewing an existing certificate

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/ricercaalternativa.mydissent.net/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/ricercaalternativa.mydissent.net/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2022-01-05. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
   again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
   "certbot renew"
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

This is the version of certbot:

```
# apt-cache policy certbot | grep Installed
  Installed: 0.31.0-2~deb10u1+ubuntu18.04.1+certbot+3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that your web server is not sending any chain certificates with your leaf certificate. This is what the SSL Labs test is trying to tell you when it says, "This server's certificate chain is incomplete".

Browsers and other clients have to guess how to verify the certificate you're sending and some are more capable/lenient than others at doing this. Safari is not. This only started happening recently due to a recent Root CA certificate expiration.

In your nginx config, you likely have a line such as:

```
ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/ricercaalternativa.mydissent.net/cert.pem;
```

If so, change `cert.pem` to `fullchain.pem` and restart nginx. Then re-check via SSL Labs and see what it says about your chain.

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan, your proposed solution works perfectly. For completeness of information for those who will look for solution to this problem, I found this little theoretical explanation: https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/ Regarding the file to be modified for a standard installation of searx, it is: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/searx-ssl